# Use input as a URL in JSP

Tags: html, jsp

I have a

```
Enter URL: <input type = "text" name= "aURL"/>
```

in my form and I want in JSP to become a clickable URL.

I tried with:

```
<% String aURL = request.getParameter("activityURL"); %>

<a href = "<%= aURL %>" ></a>
```

Comment: for this just add the `<%= aURL %>`  in between a tags thats it.. I think it was not a question. It was just a mistake. No Problem. Though Good Luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your link has no body (i.e. there's nothing between `<a>` and `</a>`), so nothing will visually appear as a clickable link. You need to give the link a body so that the enduser has *something* visible to click on.

E.g. the text "click here":

```
<a href="<%= aURL %>">click here</a>
```

or just the URL itself:

```
<a href="<%= aURL %>"><%= aURL %></a>
```

#### See also:

- [HTML Beginner Tutorial](http://htmldog.com/guides/htmlbeginner/) - [Links](http://htmldog.com/guides/htmlbeginner/links/)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: you've there a huge [XSS attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) hole with inlining user-controlled input unescaped among the HTML source code. This is pretty dangerous if your website has a sensitive backend and/or when there are sessions involved. Start learning [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)/[EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) and discover the [`fn:escapeXml()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html) function to make it XSS attack safe.

```
<a href="${fn:escapeXml(param.aURL)}">click here</a>
```